# Adding the vscode tag to a homepage tab

Tags: bug, new-nav

I have a homepage tab with the following tags as filters: [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code), [vscode-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-settings), and [vscode-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-tasks). As it stands currently, it works fine.

However, if I try to add the [vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) tag to that tab's filters, the search is narrowed down as if I had selected the `All` option for the filter parameters.

[image: Issue]

All of a sudden, there are only 9 questions listed, and all of the ones that are have at least 3 out of the 4 filter parameters as tags.

[image: Example Questions]

Is this an intended behavior?

Comment: [[tag:vscode]] is a synonym of [[tag:visual-studio-code]], so there is no point in adding the [[tag:vscode]] tag to anything. I have no idea how the new-nav is supposed to work when you add a synonym to the list, so I've avoided posting an answer, but what you're trying to do really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CodyGray You are saying that they both give the same search results? If so, why do both exist?

Comment: I'm saying that [[tag:vscode]] is a synonym of [[tag:visual-studio-code]]. "Synonym" here has the obvious meaning. The [[tag:vscode]] tag is simply *another name* for the [[tag:visual-studio-code]] tag. They are equivalent. The reason both exist is because sometimes people try to tag their question with [[tag:visual-studio-code]], and sometimes people try to tag their question with [[tag:vscode]]. They shouldn't be separate tags, since they refer to exactly the same thing, so we have made them synonyms.

Comment: read this faq https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: Aah, thanks! I understand it now. Still, the behavior is peculiar...